# gcloud app deploy error --> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am new on gcloud apps, need help on deployment web apps.

I created an App Engine and a Cloud SQL for MYSQL, it is in a different project.
Let's call App Engine as `web1` and `sql` as `mysql1`.

When I deployed `web1` using `"gcloud app deploy app.yaml"`, the upload process was success but when in the process `"Updating service"` it turns with error `"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred"`

Here is with the full error

> Updating service [default]...⠶DEBUG: Operation
> [apps/and-web-test/operations/f7c36da5-de76-436d-9e71-785d549273e0]
> complete. Result: {
>
> ```
> "metadata": {
>     "target": "apps/and-web-test/services/default/versions/and-web-mm-001", 
>     "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion", 
>     "user": "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", 
>     "insertTime": "2019-07-25T04:54:53.630Z", 
>     "endTime": "2019-07-25T04:55:11.386Z", 
>     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1"
> }, 
> "done": true, 
> "name": "apps/and-web-test/operations/f7c36da5-de76-436d-9e71-785d549273e0", 
> "error": {
>     "message": "An internal error occurred.", 
>     "code": 13
> } }
> ```

Is it because my script has a bug or something else that i need to setup like permission on the Cloud SQL project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

It was because of my folder, there was a folder called `"_ static _"` after I downloaded the code from App Engine.

I deleted it and redeployed to the App Engine was okay.

Comment: Though, what was wrong with your folder? underscore or what?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a known issue and you can see any update by the Product team via the [dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19004). Please retry the deployment after the issue is confirmed to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar error on GCP ruby demo project. Caused by manually created `.ruby-gemset` file. All works fine after deletion